# Why doesn't the Scanlogic SL11R-IDE USB-to-ATA adapter work?

Tags: 12.04, mount, hard-drive, usb-drive

I am trying to recover data from an old Linux that was installed in a computer on an ATA hard drive. I found a ScanLogic Corp. SL11R-IDE IDE Bridge (04ce:0002), an ATA adapter to USB 1.0 like the one in the picture:

[image]
and after switching it on, I plugged it into a laptop with Ubuntu 12.04. I am used to the drives being automatically mounted, but this one doesn't show up in /media. After doing a dmesg, all I got is this:

```
[215298.671924] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[215298.767330] scsi19 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[215299.841701] usb 2-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[215300.017258] usb 2-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[215300.197050] usb 2-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[215300.372730] usb 2-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
```

I tried plugging in the adapter to the three different USB ports in my laptop (one of them USB 3.0), but got no luck with any of them. I get different devices under, for example: `/dev/bus/usb/003/002` or `/dev/bus/usb/002/004`, but I don't get any `/dev/sdbN` links. The output `blkid -o list -c /dev/null` is just the laptop's partitions.

I have tried taking out the jumper, putting it as master and as CS Enabled, but didn't change the result.

If I plug it into a Windows7 laptop, the device is recognised but nothing is mounted. When I plug it into the Windows7 laptop and connect the device to a VMWare Ubuntu 12.04 session running on Windows7, I get the same results as with the Ubuntu laptop -- the `dmesg` results as above, but it is not mounted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you by any chance plugging in the adapter in a USB 3.0 port?

Comment: @SirCharlo: I tried plugging in the adapter to the three different USB ports in my laptop (one of them USB 3.0), but got no luck with any of them.

Comment: Repost? http://superuser.com/questions/470324/linux-mount-old-ata-disk-to-usb-adapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem is that your USB-IDE chipset is *very old* and known to be broken (buggy) :

- Your adapter uses the USB 1.0 [Scanlogic (now Cypress Semiconductor) SL11RIDE](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets/320/270820_DS.pdf) chipset

  - This chipset was released *sixteen* years ago, in 1996-97
  - The version you have may not even fully support the USB Mass-storage standard, which was only finalized in 1999.
- Even within a few years of release, the SL11RIDE was known to be problematic with IDE hard drives (but worked with optical drives): [example](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fosdir.com%2Fml%2Flinux.usb.user%2F2002-02%2Fmsg00127.html&ei=FyNLUPbfLqHwiwKr44HADg&usg=AFQjCNFuDWJjNkLhhvKWhKLxty9n89EX5g&sig2=QQ7Nc4CFiPK4zufhX8dU3Q&cad=rja)
- Its USB implementation is *known* to be broken, requiring special fixes in the kernel -- [see this Ubuntu bug from 8.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/336189)
- Upgrading the firmware may work, but there are two problems;

  - It requires Windows XP or lower
  - The firmware seems to be unavailable any more ([see instructions at page 9 of this PDF](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Cypress%20PDFs/SL11RIDE.pdf))

#### Simple solution

The simplest solution, therefore, appears to be to purchase a new USB-to-IDE adapter which is relatively cheap. If you can tell us your country of residence, I can try to recommend an available vendor/device which is known to work well with Linux.

#### Alternative solution: rebuild usb kernel modules after patching "unusual devices" and hope it works

- Please add a comment if you need more detailed instructions
- Get the Ubuntu kernel source
- Change to the `linux-3.2.0` directory
- In the `drivers/usb/storage/unusual_devs.h` file, find this part:

  ```
  UNUSUAL_DEV(  0x04ce, 0x0002, 0x026c, 0x026c,
              "ScanLogic",
              "SL11R-IDE",
              USB_SC_DEVICE, USB_PR_DEVICE, NULL,
              US_FL_FIX_CAPACITY),
  ```
- and edit it to change the first `0x026c` to `0x0000`, i.e. the line should read:

  ```
  UNUSUAL_DEV(  0x04ce, 0x0002, 0x0000, 0x026c,
  ```
- Then rebuild the USB storage modules and move the .ko files to the appropriate kernel under `/lib/modules`. This patch allows the unusual "fixes" to apply to all firmware versions of the SL11RIDE, not just firmware versions 2.xxx.

Answer (score 2):

I've had trouble with some old USB adapters on Ubuntu as well. I'm not experienced enough to tell you why, though. But if you have the time, you can always buy a new adapter online. They are really cheap. I got mine for 2 USD. I'm not saying it will solve your problem, but it might be worth testing, plus you usually get a s-ata adapter along as well.

Buying a new adapter worked for me. Seems like you are far more experienced than me, though. So if you are sure it's not the adapter, please ignore this answer :)